# vscode cannot open terminal unless connect to VPN

Tags: linux, bash, visual-studio-code, manjaro

Hi I'm on manjaro linux and using vscode

It was OK until once the computer went to asleep while connecting to VPN and cannot wake.

I did a hard restart by long pressing the power button, then when I start vscode, it cost extensive time to open terminal

[image]

One of the way to quick open terminal is to connect to VPN.

I'm in China now, by connect to VPN, I can access some of the net that forbidden from here.

I actually removed the system and reinstall it, but nothing works........

BTW, if I install the insider version, it is OK

Answer (score 0):

Try Pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `C` it will open terminal on that folder

Comment: Hi, when should I press it???

Comment: You can press it anywhere just make sure the folder that you want to open terminal in is open in vs code

Comment: When I have `src` subdirectory open and press `ctrl-Shift+C`, I have a terminal open but with project root folder.

Comment: Doesn't work bro......

Comment: @Philippe Yes it opens in Your Project's Folder

Comment: I meant project folder